# \tf.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: tfs, windows-xp, visual-studio-2005

Whenever i try execute TF.exe (via Windows Explorer/Command Prompt/VS2005 Command Prompt/VS2005 x64 Command Prompt) i get the error:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\tf.exe tf.exe is not a valid win32 application"

This was working before, don't remember exactly when it starting happening or why (possible due to some dumb windows/visual studio/.net security update, is my guess)

Odd thing is that Team Foundation Server operations work perfect via Visual Studio.

Anyone has a clue?

**Details**

Windows XP Pro SP3 (x86)

Visual Studio 2005 (8.0.50727.762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repaired TFS installation fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path to the executable to your PATH environment variable. Here are the instructions - https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: i repaired TFS installation, and it solved it, thanks for replying though